# Excel: preventing incrementing references when copying group of data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a pretty hard Excel question I'm seeking a solution for.  I have one Excel file with two tabs.

- Tab1: raw data
- Tab2: raw data processed and grouped for a nice lay-out for printing purposes

Contents Tab1:

```
A1 = 1
A2 = 2
A3 = 3
A4 = 4
A5 = 5
```

Contents Tab2:

```
A1 = Result
A2 ='TAB1'!A1 (a formula with reference to A1 in Tab1)
```

Wen I'm selecting A1 and A2 in Tab2 to drag/copy I get the following result:

```
A1 = Result
A2 = 1
A3 = Result
A4 = 3
A5 = Result
A6 = 5
```

The problem: when I'm selecting A1 and A2 and drag/copy, the formula thinks he has to increment with 2.  There has to be an increment by 1! The desired result is:

```
A1 = Resultaat
A2 = 1
A3 = Resultaat
A4 = 2
A5 = Resultaat
A6 = 3
A7 = Resultaat
A8 = 4
A9 = Resultaat
A10 = 5
```

Anyone has ideas or suggestion.  This is just a simpel projection.  My actual Excel has 21 rows so the increment is 21 wherever this has to be 1!

Comment: Dragging over cannot alter references by another way. Use `INDIRECT()` function to make correct reference, and `ROW()/2` to build it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using cell references (`A1` `A2` etc.), enter one more column in `Tab1` on the left and enter the data in rows as `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `A4`, `A5`. In the second column enter the results: `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` etc. When you drag `A1` and `A2` together down the rows you do get `A3`, `A4` etc. So you can enter as many as you want.

Now use '&' to concatenate the strings in cell `A1` of `Tab2` as below:

`="Result Of "&'Tab1'!A1&'Tab1'!B1`

(You need not type. Just select the relative cell of Worksheet Tab1)

Copy it down the rows to get the desired output.